# jQuery show not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show span but it doesn't work. This is the code that doesn't work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
           'onStart': function() {
                //alert("myAlert");
                $(this).siblings('span').show();
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But the span will show when I put `alert` before it, like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
           'onStart': function() {
                alert("myAlert");
                $(this).siblings('span').show();
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Why is this happening? (I use the plugin: [jquery.ajaxfileupload](https://github.com/jfeldstein/jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js))

**Edit:**
This is my html code:

```
<input type="file"/><br/>
<h1>test1</h1>
<span style="display: none;">test3</span>
<h2>test2</h2>
```

Comment: I can't imagine the `alert` has any correlation to the actual problem. Can you post your HTML markup?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @War10ck I just update.

Comment: This is happening because the alert delays the time at which the `.show()` method runs. You simply need to place this code within a callback function to a `load` or `DOMready` event. I've nominated this question to be reopened so I can more fully answer it.

Comment: whether the page is refreshed when you select a file

Comment: is .ajaxfileupload one of the jquery default functions?

Comment: @Joeytje50 I think `onStart` already a callback function..Sorry I'm very new to javascript and jquery..

Comment: @Kun yes it is a callback to the start of the ajaxfileupload, which seems to initiate immediately when the script loads. It should only run when the DOM is actually ready. See my answer below for the full explanation why that's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code runs before the DOM structure has finished loading. That causes your script to attempt to change the styles of the span before it has access to the span, so it doesn't do anything at all. To fix this, place your code within a callback, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
       'onStart': function() {
            $(this).siblings('span').show();
       }
    });
});
```

That will make the code run only after everything has loaded, which will ensure that your script can actually access the element it needs to show. When working with the DOM (which is basically everytime you need to change any HTML element), you need to put your code in such callback function.

Comment: actually I already put that in my script but not work..sorry I just update my question

Comment: @Kun could you please try putting the code `$(this).siblings('span').show();` within a setTimeout for 1 millisecond like this: `setTimeout(function() {$(this).siblings('span').show();},1);` That might have the same effect as the alert has, without the obstructive popup.

Answer (score 0):

Try a direct reference to the span

```
<input type="file"/><br/>
<button>View Span</button>
<h1>test1</h1>
<span class="myspan" style="display: none;">test3</span>
<h2>test2</h2>
```

Then

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
           'onStart': function() {
                $('.myspan').show();
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This must work

Comment: Thanks.. this work but I have 4 `input[type="file"]` so I need to use `this` to prevent `span` show in each `input[type="file"]`

Comment: first of all are you sure that `this` is the hidden field reference. print it to console in chrome eg. `console.log(this)` then find the current hidden field by expanding its attributes in console.

Comment: I think `this` is the hidden field reference. I try to put `$(this).hide();` before `$(this).siblings('span').show();` and its work fine (will hide `input[type="file"]`)..

Comment: then definitely there is some issue with `.siblings()`. Try using `$(this).parent().find('span').show();`

Comment: are you creating that span dynamically or u sure it is present there at the time of that callback.
can u create a fiddle for this.

Comment: Thanks for ur comments. I just answer my question but I think its need to be improve. I just want to get it work right now. Maybe u can give comment there